# DOM manipulation on lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, dom, lightning-datatable

I want to add attributes or classes for rows/cells in `lightning:datatable` based on cell values (I want to customize styles based on values). Is it possible? How can this be achieved?

P.S. I tried to use `document.querySelectorAll`, `document.getElementsByClassName`, etc. in 'render' event handler and in custom renderer to find rows and cells but these methods always return empty list/null. Is it due to Locker Service?

My component markup:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

    <aura:attribute name="objectList" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectColumns" type="List"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.objectList}"
                         columns="{!v.objectColumns}"
                         keyField="id"/>

</aura:component>
```

My component controller:

```
        ({
        onInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
            cmp.set('v.objectColumns', [
                {label: 'Name', fieldName: 'name', type: 'text', sortable: true},
                {label: 'Status', fieldName: 'status', type: 'text', sortable: true}
            ]);

            cmp.set('v.objectList', [
                {id: '1', name: 'object one', status: 'Active'},
                {id: '2', name: 'object two', status: 'Inactive'},
            ]);
        }
        })
```

I want to assign rows with active and inactive statuses with different css classes.

Comment: Yes, this is due to locker service. have you tried anything using the components Attributes and events available in the framework? A good place to start would be the[Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm)

Comment: @glls thanks for reply! Is there any specific attribute or event I should look at? It looks like it is not possible to add styles the way I'm used to (find nodes and then add classes to them) but maybe there is another approach in lightning?

Comment: there are different approaches, for example, from the components markup you can conditionally instantiate and render your DOM with the classes you want based on the value of x attribute. Another approach would be by creating a custom Renderer. I would suggest you look it up and try either way. Once you have some code sample working and are stuck somewhere, please update your post.

Comment: @glls added code sample. I understand what a custom renderer is, but how exactly can I find rows with it? I was going to use it for DOM search and edit but the search doesn't work so I can't obtain the nodes to edit them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the LockerService means you can't attack the problem via the DOM, but instead have to see what the component offers.

I followed the `lightning:datatable` JavaScript through in the debugger and found that the `cellAttributes` mechanism documented to support this:

```
{  
    label:'Confidence',
    fieldName:'confidence',
    type:'percent',
    cellAttributes:{  
        iconName:{  
            fieldName:'trendIcon'
        },
        iconPosition:'right'
    }
}
```

will also allow this:

```
{  
    label:'Name',
    fieldName:'Name',
    type:'text',
    cellAttributes:{  
        class:{  
            fieldName:"ClassName__c"
        }
    }
},
```

and set the DOM attribute `class` to the value of the field specified, be that a fixed value or a reference to a row field (as illustrated here).

Note too that the `fieldName` does not have to be an actual field in the SObject. In my case I have JavaScript code that works out the CSS class from other data values and adds that to the row:

```
// Convert to style
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    row._class = ...;
}
```

and then set `fieldName:"_class"`.

As a not documented feature it cannot necessarily be relied on, but seems like a valuable mechanism so I hope it will make it into the documentation and so become "official API".

Comment: Great thanks for sharing your solution! It works perfectly for setting classes for cells. Do you know if there's also a way to add classes to rows?

Comment: @user39399 I don’t think there is.

Comment: I have done this and my cell is getting the class: ```<td role="gridcell" tabindex="-1" data-label="Type" class="error">``` but the color is not getting applied.  CSS: ```.THIS .error { color: red;}```.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Inspect the content of the page to see what the CSS name is transformed to and use that name? (Sorry I don't have my example any more.)

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same answer and google led me down this path. After a little more research I discovered that the accepted answer here is outdated.

Keith C's answer **will work** and is now [documented](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/documentation) and supported (See section 'Adding Styles to Columns').

However it appears that the functionality Keith is leveraging is intended to provide row level styling support. Use the cellAttributes.class.fieldname for each column in your datatable and then vary the value of that field on each row to add individual styles to rows.

```
var columns = [
 { label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text', 
     cellAttributes:
         { class: { fieldName: 'aFieldInYourData' }}
 }, // other column data
];
```

To add style to a column simply populate the cellattribute.class property with the string value of your custom style class

```
var columns = [
 { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name', 
     cellAttributes: 
         { class: 'customCSSClass'}
 },  // other column data     
];
```

and make sure you have your custom style defined in your component.css file (Style)

```
.THIS .customCSSClass {
 color: blue;
}
```